# Best place to put my function component creator

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created a function that creates a dynamic component. Basically it receives an existent component and executes some actions in componentDidMount.

```js
import React from "react"
import { connect } from "react-redux"
import { getLeaveMessageById, deleteLeaveMessage } from "actions/leaveMessages"
import { withRouter } from "react-router"

export const withLeaveMessage = (leaveMessageId, Component) => {
  const Container = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount: function() {
      this.props.router.setRouteLeaveHook(
        this.props.route,
        this.routerWillLeave
      )
    },
    componentWillUnmount: function() {
      this.props.deleteLeaveMessage("proposalForm")
    },
    routerWillLeave: function(){
      return this.props.leaveMessage
    },
    render: function() {
      return <Component/>
    }
  })

  const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
      leaveMessage: getLeaveMessageById(leaveMessageId, state)
    }
  }

  const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return { deleteLeaveMessage }
  }

  return withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Container))
}
```

So, what is the better place to put it? Ex. components, containers, utils, etc

Comment: To me this seems like it follows the decorator pattern. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern I'd call it a decorator, and put into a folder of 'decorators'. Naming and organizing stuff is hard.

Comment: Yeah decorators, or hoc, or wrappers.. you can't go wrong.